# While loop not exiting with `while(x!='\n')`

Tags: c

Why is this while loop not exiting ?

I want to input a series of number from users and then use them one by one for further processing. I do not have the size of numbers list. Can someone please tell me how to do this ?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(x!='\n')
    { 
        printf("%d",x);
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

Input:

```
3 5 6
```

Output:

```
3 5 6
```

Actual Output:

```
3 5 6
```

but loop doesn't exit

Comment: First, start by formatting your code correctly. Second, consult the documentation for `scanf`, and third, quit ignoring its return value.

Comment: Read a line of input and use `strtok()` to parse it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2624/) is a good website. There is an interesting program on it. You may play with it and learn from it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
while(scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) {
    printf("%d",x);
    if (getchar() == '\n') break; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `%d` conversion specifier never *stores* the `\n` into the buffer. It reads up to the `\n` in the buffer and leaves it there. So, this is *essentially* an infinite loop.

You may need to use a format specifier like `%c` which actually *reads* and stores the `\n`.

Although, if I may suggest, try to make use of [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar), which reads the next *character* from the standard input and returns the value as an `int`. However, for an input of *digits*, you need to parse and store the integer and/or float  value accordingly, but it will certainly provide you more flexibility.

Comment: how to use getchar()?

Comment: @user3550981: You might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `argv` and `strtol` ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0, x;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        x = strtol(argv[i],NULL,10);
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanf("%d",&x) != EOF) {
   printf("%d",x);
}
```

...would do it. Don't ignore scanf returns. The reason your code is looping is you're really comparing x against decimal value of 10 ('\n'). Also, please remember that you asked scanf to give you integers and that's what it gives you, it will not give you newlines, even if it could.

Edited, so that I added comparison to EOF specifically.
You need to remember that scanf scans a stream, in this case the input stream, it will not return until that stream is done.

You should really use strings and sscanf() for what you want to do.

Comment: No..its not working. The loop is still not exiting . Its printing the input but not exiting.